# MySQL / Find values in a set that aren't in a column

Tags: mysql

I have some data which contains a comma separated list and three columns.  What I'd like is to find the values that exist in the list but not in any column.

**DATA**:

```
+-------+-------+--------+-----------------+
| col_a | col_b | col_c  | list            |
+-------+-------+--------+-----------------+
| red   | NULL  | green  | yellow,blue     |
| red   | blue  | green  | red,blue,green  |
| red   | NULL  | yellow | green           |
| blue  | white | green  | red,white,green |
| NULL  | NULL  | NULL   | red,blue,green  |
+-------+-------+--------+-----------------+
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

```
+-------+-------+--------+-----------------+----------------+
| col_a | col_b | col_c  | list            | unmatched      |
+-------+-------+--------+-----------------+----------------+
| red   | NULL  | green  | yellow,blue     | yellow,blue    |
| red   | blue  | green  | red,blue,green  |                |
| red   | NULL  | yellow | green           | green          |
| blue  | white | green  | red,white,green | red            |
| NULL  | NULL  | NULL   | red,blue,green  | red,blue,green |
+-------+-------+--------+-----------------+----------------+
```

At the moment I have a query that works but it's very ugly:

```
SELECT *,
TRIM(
    BOTH ',' FROM 
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                    LIST,
                    IFNULL(col_a,''),
                    ''
                ),
                IFNULL(col_b,''),
                ''
            ),
            IFNULL(col_c,'')
            ,''
        ),
        ',,',
        ','
    )
) AS unmatched
FROM color_list
```

Is there a cleaner way to find the `unmatched` values? The thing I'm doing here would be really hard to scale and feels quite awkward and fragile.

[Here's a fiddle.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/isonNtr8fMH3T4bZ6yeHRs/0)

Comment: Is the number of items in the list column always 3?

Comment: @JeffBreadner - no, not necessarily.  Sorry, I should have provided more variation — updated question with a more diverse data set.

Comment: I thought i'd have some insight for this one, I was wrong.  What you've got is already far more elegant and performant than anything I could do; I tried your new data in Fiddle and your existing solution already works with a dynamic (even >3) number of items in the list column.  Someone else may be able to improve on what you've got, but I can't.

Comment: Well thanks for giving it a whirl @JeffBreadner.

Comment: Do you have a unique id in this table? Currently i dont find a better solution, but a more ugly one :D
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dGqEfRyWjHKLCwVG3pnA4T/2

Comment: @SteffenMächtel - no.  See fiddle for schema.  Would that be helpful?

Comment: hahaha... well I'd give you a +1 for creativity anyway.  Knowing different approaches is good for brain.

Comment: The same ugly one, but without the need of id :D
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dGqEfRyWjHKLCwVG3pnA4T/4
I give up. Maybe someone else find a good solution :D
I am missing something like php explode() in mysql :'(